# Redimensionar un frame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Me gustaría poder redimensionar un frame de `tkinter` dentro de una raíz usando solo el mouse, es hacer un frame más grande o más pequeño dentro de la ventana principal si me es necesario por alguna razón. He intentado utilizar `resizable`, como en la raíz, pero no ha funcionado. ¿Es posible hacerlo?

Os dejo el código que he usado como mini ejemplo.

¡Un saludo y muchas gracias por adelantado!

```py
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

raiz.config(width="1000", height ="600")

frame1=Frame(raiz,width=200,height=200)

frame1.config(bd=5,bg='blue',relief="ridge")

frame1.pack()

frame2=Frame(raiz,width=300,height=300)
frame2.config(bd=5,bg='green',relief="ridge")
#frame2.resizable(True, True)
frame2.pack()

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te sirve el [widget sizegrip](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-sizegrip/)? De lo contrario, será necesario hacer una función que haga eso.

Comment: según he estado probando, si lo he programado bien, solo funciona para la raiz principal, no para los diferentes frames, pero voy a seguir intentándolo! Muchas gracias!!